# Splitting a time-representing string and extracting value in seconds

Tags: r, string, time

I am trying to write a function that would take time in a string like "mm:ss.sss" (e. g. 1:23.242) and return total seconds (in this case 83.242).

This is my attempt:

```
get_time <- function(str){
  minutes = strsplit(str,split=":")[0]
  seconds = strsplit(str,split=":")[1]
  return((60.0)*as.numeric(minutes)+as.numeric(seconds))
}
```

I figured there is some problem with strsplit function. I know [it returns a list](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strsplit), but accessing the elements by [] doesn't seem to work, even though they say so in [the tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/r-list-tutorial/#:%7E:text=R%20list%20is%20the%20object,generic%20vector%20containing%20other%20objects.).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things: (1) `strsplit` returns a list, so you could try using `unlist` as follows: `unlist(strsplit(str, split = ":"))` ... and (2) R is 1-indexed (not 0-indexed), so you will want `[1]` for minutes and `[2]` for seconds...putting both together you will have `minutes = unlist(strsplit(str,split=":"))[1]` and `seconds = unlist(strsplit(str,split=":"))[2]`...

Comment: Also, with regards to subsetting a list, would take a look at [this reference](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html). In your case, you could subset in a number of ways, without using `unlist`...such as `[[c(1,1)]]` for minutes and `[[c(1,2)]]` for seconds...

Comment: Thanks, it has solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

There are functions in the `lubridate` package that will do a lot of this for you. Here is some sample code that uses the `ms` function which reads minutes and seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
timestring <- '1:23.242'
ms <- ms(timestring)
seconds <- as.numeric(as.duration(ms))
seconds
# [1] 83.242
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
> as.numeric(unlist(str_split('1:23.56', ":"))) %*% c(60,1)
      [,1]
[1,] 83.56
```